# Legend in Base R: Can fill refrain from drawing boxes on some lines? Can fill draw boxes that cover the whole symbol?

Tags: r, graphics, fill, legend

I have a plot with overlapping shaded confidence intervals that looks like this:

[image: portion of the graph]

and I would like very much to annotate the legend with the color of the confidence interval. Something like:

[image: legend section]

except, I'd like two things:

1. for the boxes not to show up on the first two entries.
2. for the boxes to stretch across the dot and the rightmost portion of the line on the last three entries.

(And I'm using base R instead of ggplot2 for a couple of reasons specific to this application that aren't really relevant to explain.)

Here is a code example that reproduces the legend:

```
#Build a fake plot so that legend has somewhere to sit
xx <- seq(0,10,by=.1)
yy <- 2*xx + rnorm(length(xx),0,1)
plot(xx,yy)

#Build the legend
estNames <- c('est1','est2','est3')
legend('bottomright', 
        c("no box, no point","no box, no point",estNames) , 
        lty=c(rep('dotted',2),rep('solid',3)), 
        col=c('black','red',1,2,4),
        pch=c(-1,-1,rep(16,3)),
        lwd=1,
        fill=c( 0, 0,
            rep( c( rgb(0.5,0.5,0.1,0.25),
                rgb(0.5,0.1,0.1,0.25),
                rgb(0.1,0.1,0.5,0.25)), 2)),
        inset=0,bg='white')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ugly *ad hoc* solution, but seems to work.

[image]

To remove the border around the symbols, use the `border` argument. Adjust colors according to your background.

```
legend.v2('bottomright', 
        c("no box, no point","no box, no point",estNames) , 
        lty=c(rep('dotted',2),rep('solid',3)), 
        col=c('black','red',1,2,4),
        pch=c(-1,-1,rep(16,3)),
        lwd=1,
        border = c("white", "white", "black", "black", "black"),
        trace = TRUE,
        fill=c( 0, 0,
                rep( c( rgb(0.5,0.5,0.1,0.25),
                                rgb(0.5,0.1,0.1,0.25),
                                rgb(0.1,0.1,0.5,0.25)), 2)),
        inset=0,bg='white')
```

The function that draws rectangles around the symbols is `?rect`.
I've multiplied the `xbox` argument by 3 (scroll down to the `if (mfill)` line). The correct factor of multiplication is probably a bit less, experiment.

```
legend.v2 <- function (x, y = NULL, legend, fill = NULL, col = par("col"), 
        border = "black", lty, lwd, pch, angle = 45, density = NULL, 
        bty = "o", bg = par("bg"), box.lwd = par("lwd"), box.lty = par("lty"), 
        box.col = par("fg"), pt.bg = NA, cex = 1, pt.cex = cex, pt.lwd = lwd, 
        xjust = 0, yjust = 1, x.intersp = 1, y.intersp = 1, adj = c(0, 
                0.5), text.width = NULL, text.col = par("col"), merge = do.lines && 
                has.pch, trace = FALSE, plot = TRUE, ncol = 1, horiz = FALSE, 
        title = NULL, inset = 0, xpd, title.col = text.col, title.adj = 0.5, 
        seg.len = 2) 
{
    if (missing(legend) && !missing(y) && (is.character(y) || 
                is.expression(y))) {
        legend <- y
        y <- NULL
    }
    mfill <- !missing(fill) || !missing(density)
    if (!missing(xpd)) {
        op <- par("xpd")
        on.exit(par(xpd = op))
        par(xpd = xpd)
    }
    title <- as.graphicsAnnot(title)
    if (length(title) > 1) 
        stop("invalid title")
    legend <- as.graphicsAnnot(legend)
    n.leg <- if (is.call(legend)) 
                1
            else length(legend)
    if (n.leg == 0) 
        stop("'legend' is of length 0")
    auto <- if (is.character(x)) 
                match.arg(x, c("bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", 
                                "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", "right", "center"))
            else NA
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        xy <- xy.coords(x, y)
        x <- xy$x
        y <- xy$y
        nx <- length(x)
        if (nx < 1 || nx > 2) 
            stop("invalid coordinate lengths")
    }
    else nx <- 0
    xlog <- par("xlog")
    ylog <- par("ylog")
    rect2 <- function(left, top, dx, dy, density = NULL, angle, 
            ...) {
        r <- left + dx
        if (xlog) {
            left <- 10^left
            r <- 10^r
        }
        b <- top - dy
        if (ylog) {
            top <- 10^top
            b <- 10^b
        }
        rect(left, top, r, b, angle = angle, density = density, 
                ...)
    }
    segments2 <- function(x1, y1, dx, dy, ...) {
        x2 <- x1 + dx
        if (xlog) {
            x1 <- 10^x1
            x2 <- 10^x2
        }
        y2 <- y1 + dy
        if (ylog) {
            y1 <- 10^y1
            y2 <- 10^y2
        }
        segments(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
    }
    points2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog) 
            y <- 10^y
        points(x, y, ...)
    }
    text2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog) 
            y <- 10^y
        text(x, y, ...)
    }
    if (trace) 
        catn <- function(...) do.call("cat", c(lapply(list(...), 
                                    formatC), list("\n")))
    cin <- par("cin")
    Cex <- cex * par("cex")
    if (is.null(text.width)) 
        text.width <- max(abs(strwidth(legend, units = "user", 
                                cex = cex)))
    else if (!is.numeric(text.width) || text.width < 0) 
        stop("'text.width' must be numeric, >= 0")
    xc <- Cex * xinch(cin[1L], warn.log = FALSE)
    yc <- Cex * yinch(cin[2L], warn.log = FALSE)
    if (xc < 0) 
        text.width <- -text.width
    xchar <- xc
    xextra <- 0
    yextra <- yc * (y.intersp - 1)
    ymax <- yc * max(1, strheight(legend, units = "user", cex = cex)/yc)
    ychar <- yextra + ymax
    if (trace) 
        catn("  xchar=", xchar, "; (yextra,ychar)=", c(yextra, 
                        ychar))
    if (mfill) {
        xbox <- xc * 0.8
        ybox <- yc * 0.5
        dx.fill <- xbox
    }
    do.lines <- (!missing(lty) && (is.character(lty) || any(lty > 
                                    0))) || !missing(lwd)
    n.legpercol <- if (horiz) {
                if (ncol != 1) 
                    warning("horizontal specification overrides: Number of columns := ", 
                            n.leg)
                ncol <- n.leg
                1
            }
            else ceiling(n.leg/ncol)
    has.pch <- !missing(pch) && length(pch) > 0
    if (do.lines) {
        x.off <- if (merge) 
                    -0.7
                else 0
    }
    else if (merge) 
        warning("'merge = TRUE' has no effect when no line segments are drawn")
    if (has.pch) {
        if (is.character(pch) && !is.na(pch[1L]) && nchar(pch[1L], 
                type = "c") > 1) {
            if (length(pch) > 1) 
                warning("not using pch[2..] since pch[1L] has multiple chars")
            np <- nchar(pch[1L], type = "c")
            pch <- substr(rep.int(pch[1L], np), 1L:np, 1L:np)
        }
    }
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- log10(x)
        if (ylog) 
            y <- log10(y)
    }
    if (nx == 2) {
        x <- sort(x)
        y <- sort(y)
        left <- x[1L]
        top <- y[2L]
        w <- diff(x)
        h <- diff(y)
        w0 <- w/ncol
        x <- mean(x)
        y <- mean(y)
        if (missing(xjust)) 
            xjust <- 0.5
        if (missing(yjust)) 
            yjust <- 0.5
    }
    else {
        h <- (n.legpercol + (!is.null(title))) * ychar + yc
        w0 <- text.width + (x.intersp + 1) * xchar
        if (mfill) 
            w0 <- w0 + dx.fill
        if (do.lines) 
            w0 <- w0 + (seg.len + +x.off) * xchar
        w <- ncol * w0 + 0.5 * xchar
        if (!is.null(title) && (abs(tw <- strwidth(title, units = "user", 
                                    cex = cex) + 0.5 * xchar)) > abs(w)) {
            xextra <- (tw - w)/2
            w <- tw
        }
        if (is.na(auto)) {
            left <- x - xjust * w
            top <- y + (1 - yjust) * h
        }
        else {
            usr <- par("usr")
            inset <- rep(inset, length.out = 2)
            insetx <- inset[1L] * (usr[2L] - usr[1L])
            left <- switch(auto, bottomright = , topright = , 
                    right = usr[2L] - w - insetx, bottomleft = , 
                    left = , topleft = usr[1L] + insetx, bottom = , 
                    top = , center = (usr[1L] + usr[2L] - w)/2)
            insety <- inset[2L] * (usr[4L] - usr[3L])
            top <- switch(auto, bottomright = , bottom = , bottomleft = usr[3L] + 
                            h + insety, topleft = , top = , topright = usr[4L] - 
                            insety, left = , right = , center = (usr[3L] + 
                                usr[4L] + h)/2)
        }
    }
    if (plot && bty != "n") {
        if (trace) 
            catn("  rect2(", left, ",", top, ", w=", w, ", h=", 
                    h, ", ...)", sep = "")
        rect2(left, top, dx = w, dy = h, col = bg, density = NULL, 
                lwd = box.lwd, lty = box.lty, border = box.col)
    }
    xt <- left + xchar + xextra + (w0 * rep.int(0:(ncol - 1), 
                rep.int(n.legpercol, ncol)))[1L:n.leg]
    yt <- top - 0.5 * yextra - ymax - (rep.int(1L:n.legpercol, 
                        ncol)[1L:n.leg] - 1 + (!is.null(title))) * ychar
    if (mfill) {
        if (plot) {
            fill <- rep(fill, length.out = n.leg)
            rect2(left = xt, top = yt + ybox/2, dx = xbox * 3, dy = ybox, 
                    col = fill, density = density, angle = angle, 
                    border = border)
        }
        xt <- xt + dx.fill
    }
    if (plot && (has.pch || do.lines)) 
        col <- rep(col, length.out = n.leg)
    if (missing(lwd)) 
        lwd <- par("lwd")
    if (do.lines) {
        if (missing(lty)) 
            lty <- 1
        lty <- rep(lty, length.out = n.leg)
        lwd <- rep(lwd, length.out = n.leg)
        ok.l <- !is.na(lty) & (is.character(lty) | lty > 0)
        if (trace) 
            catn("  segments2(", xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, ",", 
                    yt[ok.l], ", dx=", seg.len * xchar, ", dy=0, ...)")
        if (plot) 
            segments2(xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, yt[ok.l], dx = seg.len * 
                            xchar, dy = 0, lty = lty[ok.l], lwd = lwd[ok.l], 
                    col = col[ok.l])
        xt <- xt + (seg.len + x.off) * xchar
    }
    if (has.pch) {
        pch <- rep(pch, length.out = n.leg)
        pt.bg <- rep(pt.bg, length.out = n.leg)
        pt.cex <- rep(pt.cex, length.out = n.leg)
        pt.lwd <- rep(pt.lwd, length.out = n.leg)
        ok <- !is.na(pch) & (is.character(pch) | pch >= 0)
        x1 <- (if (merge && do.lines) 
                xt - (seg.len/2) * xchar
            else xt)[ok]
        y1 <- yt[ok]
        if (trace) 
            catn("  points2(", x1, ",", y1, ", pch=", pch[ok], 
                    ", ...)")
        if (plot) 
            points2(x1, y1, pch = pch[ok], col = col[ok], cex = pt.cex[ok], 
                    bg = pt.bg[ok], lwd = pt.lwd[ok])
    }
    xt <- xt + x.intersp * xchar
    if (plot) {
        if (!is.null(title)) 
            text2(left + w * title.adj, top - ymax, labels = title, 
                    adj = c(title.adj, 0), cex = cex, col = title.col)
        text2(xt, yt, labels = legend, adj = adj, cex = cex, 
                col = text.col)
    }
    invisible(list(rect = list(w = w, h = h, left = left, top = top), 
                    text = list(x = xt, y = yt)))
}
```

Comment: I never would have though to dig into the source. I guess that's part of the beauty of R; you can mess with things that even seem like 'commands'. So, if I understand the solution, you typed `legend` into the console to get the code that R was using. Then you found the part of that code that drew the rectangles and modified it appropriately. This is awesome, thank you! (And thank you for pointing me in the correct direction for `border`!)

Comment: That's how I did it. Sometimes you can't see the code, and you have to download the source. If you're lucky, source files are well documented which can help you guide through the process. I created a new function to avoid overlapping with the original one (I even stored it into a new file because that's how I work).